# Deleting max value in set without max()

Tags: python, set

I have a working code

```
task = set()
x = 1

while x != 0:
    x = int(input('input your number '))
    task.add(x)
    print('Just 0 could stop it!')

task.remove(max(task))
print(max(task))
```

And need to get the same result without using max(). What could be an alternative?

Comment: Sorry, but here you use max() anymore (print(max(task))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `min` with a `key` arg that inverts the element:

```
>>> task = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> max(task)
5
>>> min(task, key=lambda x: -x)
5
```

Or you could `sort` it and take the last element...

```
>>> sorted(task)[-1]
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, unless you have really large sets, I don`t see the advantage

```
task = set()
x = 1
m = 0
while x != 0:
    x = int(input('input your number '))
    task.add(x)
    if x > m:
        m = x
    print('Just 0 could stop it!')

task.remove(m)
print(max(task))
```

Notice this will only work for positive numbers, if you want to the complete int range you should init `m` like this `m = -sys.maxsize - 1`

Comment: This answer still uses `max()`...

Comment: @Samwise The task was to delete the max value without using `max()`  and my code still does that, without the need of sorting the whole list. I assumed `print(max(task))` is just there for debugging.